# How to migrate a database from Oracle to MySQL using the command line?

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration

I am trying to migrate a database from Oracle to MySQL, with exp .dmp but I run into the problem that I must convert the .dmp file to .sql so that mysql recognizes it, for this conversion I cannot find a method in Windows.

This is the way I export my database:

```
`exp userid=delitos/password93210@xe tables=(muni,informe) file=D:/Escritorio/ExportOracle/delitos_backup.dmp`
```

I tried to use linux using wsl ubuntu on my computer, but I would really like to use only windows for this process

Comment: Unless you're on good terms with Oracle and have a host with Oracle DB installed you're going to struggle - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63152029/how-to-convert-dmp-file-to-sql-file-in-pl-sql https://eternusuk.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-convert-oracle-dmp-into-more.html

Comment: The dmp files produced by exp and expdp are binary, proprietary formatted files that will have no meaning to MySQL. exp and expdp can both produce SQL DDL command text as an option, but this will be Oracle-specific DDL and will need conversion to work with MySQL. Data can be moved with some other 3rd party ETL tool like NiFi once the data model is implemented in MySQL.